# Testing S3 Replication Failure CloudWatch Alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

Scenario:
I have S3 replication set up so when a file lands in our active region bucket it is replicated to our passive region bucket. I would like to create a CloudWatch Alarm to raise an alert when S3 replication fails ***and test that rule***.

The Issue:
I can't bring down S3 or a region to test this scenario.

Question:
Is there a way to make S3 replication to my passive region fail in order to trigger the alarm?

I found this list of S3 Replication Failure codes, but I'm not sure how I'd implement them to cause a failure: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-failure-codes.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

Make Changes to Replication Configuration:
Temporarily tweak the replication settings of your S3 bucket in the active region to deliberately introduce an error—consider modifying the destination bucket name or the associated IAM role.

Trigger Replication:
Upload a test file to the source bucket in the active region to kickstart replication. Since we intentionally modified the replication configuration, this action is expected to lead to a replication failure.

Configure CloudWatch Alarms:
Set up a CloudWatch Alarm that monitors S3 replication metrics, such as ReplicationLatency or ReplicationTime. Adjust the alarm threshold to generate an alert if replication encounters unusual delays or errors.

Undo Configuration Adjustments:
After completing the testing phase, restore the replication configuration to its original state to return to normal replication behavior.